# Он - мудрец, она - ?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Понятно, что наш русский язык "заточен" под мужской род. Например, человек, обладающий мудростью, - мудрец. Но женщины тоже бывают мудрыми (правда, в последнее время все реже))), но как сказать одним словом о мудрой женщине? Мудрица? Это чисто по аналогии со "старец - старица". Или такого слова в русском языке нет вообще, и надо говорить просто "мудрая женщина"?

Answer (score 3):

О существовании суффиксов ЕЦ/ИЦ. я думаю, Вам известно. Если говорим о мужчине, который владеет чем-то, то говорим *владелец*. Если говорим о женщине, то используем суффикс ИЦ и добавляем окончание А. Получаем слово *владелица*. Я думаю, что слова запрещено создавать, так что перед употреблением Вам следует посмотреть в толковый словарь. Коли не существует такое слово, не используйте его. :)

Кстати, можно вообще просто использовать прилагательное в женском роде (мудрая).

Comment: Правильно.

Comment: Что правильно?! Вы на вопрос человеку ответьте, пожалуйста!

Comment: "Коли" - иначе  "если".  Существует.

Comment: Если слова запрещено создавать, то откуда они взялись-то да еще в таком количестве?

Comment: Слова-то можно создавать. Но их лексическое значение должно быть понятным. Если такое слово не существует, то зачем его употреблять?

Comment: Все слова когда-то не существовали.

Comment: Хорошо. Раз слова можно создавать, то в этом случае Luke - автор нового слова "Мудрица". Ура!

Answer (score 2):

Русский  язык  не  заточен  под  мужской  пол.  Пары  есть  к  многим  словам.  И  не  обязательно  это  слова  бытового  ряда.  Старец  -  старица,  святой  -  святая,  царь  -  царица.  Генералиц,  правда  нет,  но  и  женщин  в  этом  звании  негусто.  В  этом  случае  слова  нет  за  ненужностью.  Мудрых  женщин  не  меньше,  чем  мудрых  мужчин,  но  слова  тоже  нет.  Грамматически  создать  его  можно,  но  ведь  не  создалось  же.  Мудрых  женщин  от  этого  не  убавилось.  Может,  "мудрица"  звучит  неприятно ?  Может,  вызывает  какие - нибудь  ассоциации ?  Можно  ли  говорить  о  какой-то  заточке  русского  языка  только  на  том  основании,  что    учительница  есть,  а  врачицы  -  нет?  Или  утверждать  на  этом  основании,  что  женщина-учитель  народу  нужней,  чем  женщина-врач ?  Действительно,  язык  официальных  документов  для  обозначения  профессий  и  званий использует  слова  мужского  рода,  но  это  проблема  только  для  феминисток.

Comment: А  под  какой  пол  заточено  слово  "судья" ?  В  современном  русском  языке  это  слово  женского  рода.  Дискриминация  мужчин ?

Comment: Честно говоря, не понимаю, где тут какая дискриминация? Мне, например, кажется, что автор имел в виду лишь то, что, например, за исходный вариант всегда берется мужской род, и ничего более.

Comment: А почему это слово женского рода, в  словарях  указывается мужской род, или два рода, или общий род,например:Существительное, одушевлённое, общий род (может согласовываться с другими частями речи как мужского, так и женского рода), 1-е склонение (тип склонения 6*d по классификации А. Зализняка).

Comment: Совершенно  верно,  нет  никакой  дискриминации.  Но  и  "заточки"  нет.

Comment: Эту тему (про судью) уже обсуждали http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/24076/грамотная-речь-какого-рода-слово-судья

Comment: София,  в  каком  словаре  судья  не  женского  рода ?  Скиньте  ссылку.  По  вашей  ссылке  слова  обозначающие  профессии  не  могут  быть  словами  общего  рода.

Comment: http://udarenieru.ru/index.php?doc=судья

http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%F1%F3%E4%FC%FF

В словарях на Грамоте.ру м. и ж. род или м. род

Comment: Да...  Отстал  я  от  жизни.

Answer (score 2):

И женщина может быть мудрецом.

Специальные "женские" формы для слов типа "мудрец","гордец","молодец" или необязательны к употреблению, или вовсе отсутствуют.

Хотя, если обязательно надо найти когда-то существовавший (или возможно существовавший) женский вариант, то искать конечно, надо мудр**и**ца - мудрая женщина и мудреч**и**ха - жена мудреца.

Comment: "Специальные "женские" формы для слов типа "мудрец","гордец","молодец" или необязательны к употреблению, или вовсе отсутствуют."

Правду молвить, молодица
Уж и впрямь была царица:
Высока, стройна, бела....

Answer (score 0):

Женщина, обладающая мудростью - мудреница или [мудреца](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B0)

мудр -> мудрец -> мудр**ен**ица;
ток -> миро(точец) -> точ**ен**ица 
       багрец -> багр**ян**ица